# Bounce rate issues

Tags: usability, bounce-rate

I currently have a site which shows the best uk speaker deals and I am having bounce rate problems.

The site simply allows the user to search for the best deals and then go to the provider’s site (this is a non profit site).

What I didn’t anticipate is that people are going straight to the deal details from Google (organic) and missing out the listing pages. The users then either go off to the deals or bounce.

Either way my bounce rate is quite high at 54% and my event tracking says 25% of people are clicking on my ‘go to deal’ button ([example](http://www.soundplaza.co.uk/speakers/47/tannoy-revolution-signature-dc6)).

Overall I wish to lower my bounce rate so that Google doesn’t think my site is bad and hopefully make a more pleasant experience for my users.

Questions:

1. Do you think the site/ user would benefit from a page in-between the link button and the provider’s page. This would say something on the lines of “you will now be transferred to the providers site in 5 seconds”. This therefore warms up the user to the new website and cancels out the bounce.
2. Given that I have an Analytics Event on each ‘go to deal’ button, will Google recognise this and not consider it a bounce?
3. Should I put less emphasis on the ‘go to deal’ button and more availability to go to other products on the site.
4. Is the page taking too long to load therefore the analytics code doesn’t register?

Home of the website - http://www.soundplaza.co.uk

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thought is to give users reasons to stay on the site and do more.  For instance you could have a shadow box that pops up after a user clicks on the get deal button that shows them similar deals or you could add a level of engagement with a comments section and social media share buttons.

Comment: OK interesting... I was thinking of adding other products below the image and above the main features to recycle the users, but maybe a pop up is a good idea!

Comment: just implimented the pop up box ;) that's for advice... lets see how this goes!

Comment: Is your bounce rate of 54 percent that bad?  Mine is 70 percent!